# What's the best way to manage view in WPF project with MVVM (.Net 6)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, .net-6.0

First, I apologize if my question seems "easy." I'm kind of a beginner in WPF.

I have to upgrade an old WPF project designed with .Net Framework 4.5.2 to .Net 6 (with some other improvements).

The migration from .Net Framework 4.5.2 to .Net 6 is complete, and it works quite well.

However, in the old project, there is a MainView with a menu, and each menu item opens a new window using ShowDialog(). In these new windows, you can also open additional windows using ShowDialog(), and so on.

As a result, you can end up with four windows open, but the first three are frozen (let it go, let it go, sorry XD) because of ShowDialog(). You have to close the fourth window, then the third, then the second before reaching the mainWindow.

It looks really messy.

I want to improve this situation by having only one active/visible window without rewriting the entire project.

Currently, MainView (MainView.xaml.cs) opens a new window using the following code:

```
var v = new MyNewView();
v.Owner = this;
v.ShowDialog();
```

In this new view you get the viewmodel with the following :

```
public MyNewView()
{
        DataContext = ViewModelLocator.GetViewModelInstance<ModelContext, MyNewViewModel>(this);
        InitializeComponent();
}
```

(ModelContext is a DBContext)

And the ViewModelLocator is something like that :

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(
            new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<ApplicationContext>()
            .AddTransient<MainViewModel>()
            .AddTransient<MyNewViewModel>()
            .BuildServiceProvider());
    }

    public static Tvm GetViewModelInstance<TContext, Tvm>(ICloseableEvent w, bool initializeContext = true) where Tvm : IDisposable where TContext : ModelContext
    {
        Tvm VMInstance = Ioc.Default.GetService<Tvm>();
        if (initializeContext)
            (VMInstance as CommonViewModel<TContext>)!.InitializeContext();
        w.Closed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.UnregisterAll(VMInstance);
            VMInstance.Dispose();
        };
        return VMInstance;
    }
}
```

The solution I've found is to define a ContentControl in the MainView.xaml, like that :

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MainContent"/>
```

and then, instead of opening a new window with "ShowDialog", I simply replace the content of the MainView with the content of the MyNewView, like this (in MainView.xaml.cs) :

```
MyNewView myNewView = new MyNewView();
myNewView.Owner = App.MainView;

App.MainView.MainContent.Content = myNewView.Content;
App.MainView.Title = myNewView.Title;

myNewView.Close();
```

And if I close "MyNewView," I simply reset the MainContent with the content of the MainView. It works (but I'm not sure if it's a good solution). However, the view model doesn't change. The view still looks for MainViewModel instead of MyNewViewModel, even if the "DataContext = ViewModelLocator.GetViewModelInstance<ModelContext, MyNewViewModel>(this);" is called correctly.

So, I don't think it's a good solution after all.

What is the best way to navigate from one view to another in a WPF application (with MVVM in .Net 6)?

- Is it better to convert Window to UserControl (except for the MainView)?
- Is there a better way to invoke a view?

Please let me know if you need more details, and please be understanding as I'm fairly new to WPF and I just want to do things the right way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The approach I would usually choose as default is single window and viewmodel first.
With this, you have a viewmodel associated with a usercontrol as template.  You can see a very simple version here:  https://github.com/AndyONeill/WPF_NavigationViewModelFirst

Comment: An extension of this approach uses the mainwindow purely as a container. That then allows you to easily have a login view fills mainwindow initially and then when the user logs in they get menus etc plus which remain static whilst a panel content changes.

Comment: Here's an example of that approach https://github.com/AndyONeill/LoginNavigation